# Manually connect barbutton outlet to action through code

Tags: swift, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem, iboutlet

I have managed to code four UIBarButton items that appear when I run my app. However, when I click on one of the buttons (to go to a new screen), the app crashes with a SIGBART error. I know from previous experiences that this may be caused by not having outlets connect. But because I have coded the buttons to appear in my file, I am unsure of how to connect the outlet and actions through code. Any guidance would be much appreciated!

```
    import UIKit

    class navigationToolBar: UINavigationController, UIToolbarDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var searchBarButton1: UIBarButtonItem!


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            print(UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height)//44 for iPhone x, 20 for other iPhones
            navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .blue
            self.toolbar.barTintColor = UIColor.black

            var searchicon = UIImage(named: "searchicon")!
            var protocolsicon = UIImage(named: "protocolsicon")!
            var homeicon = UIImage(named: "homeicon")!
            var toolsicon = UIImage(named: "toolsicon")!


            let search1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "searchn") as! UINavigationController
            let protocols1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "protocolsn") as! UINavigationController
            let home1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homen") as! UINavigationController
         //   let tools1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateInitialViewController(withIdentifier: "initial") as! imageViewController
          //  let info1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Information") as! imageViewController

            let toolBar = UIToolbar()
            var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()


            var searchBarButton1 = UIBarButtonItem(image: searchicon, style: .plain, target: self, action: Selector(("opensearchbar1")))



            items.append(
                UIBarButtonItem(image: searchicon, style: .plain, target: self, action: Selector(("opensearchbar1")))
            )
            items.append(
                UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
            )
            items.append(
                UIBarButtonItem(image: protocolsicon, style: .plain, target: self, action: Selector(("opensearchbar")))
            )
            items.append(
                UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
            )
            items.append(
                UIBarButtonItem(image: homeicon, style: .plain, target: self, action: Selector(("onClickBarButton:")))
            )
            items.append(
                UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
            )
            items.append(
                UIBarButtonItem(image: toolsicon, style: .plain, target: self, action: Selector(("onClickBarButton:")))
            )
            items.append(
                UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
            )
            items.append(
                UIBarButtonItem(image: toolsicon, style: .plain, target: self, action: Selector(("onClickBarButton:")))
            )


            func opensearchbar(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

                switch sender.tag {
                case 1:
                    print("1")
                    break;
               case 2:
                    print("error")
                    break;
                case 3:
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(protocols1, animated: true)
                    break;
                case 4:
                    print("error")
                    break;
                case 5:
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(home1, animated: true)
                    break;
                case 6:
                    print("error")
                    break;
                case 7:
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(home1, animated: true)
                    break;
                case 8:
                    print("error")
                    break;
              //  case 9:
              //      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(info1, animated: true)
              //      break;
                default:
                  print("ERROR!!")
                }
            }



            toolBar.setItems(items, animated: true)
            toolBar.tintColor = .blue
            toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
            toolBar.isTranslucent = true
            view.addSubview(toolBar)

            toolBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                let guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
                toolBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
                toolBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
                toolBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
                toolBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true

            }
            else {
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: toolBar, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: toolBar, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: toolBar, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true

                toolBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
            }

    }

func opensearchbar1 (_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
let search1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "searchn") as! ViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(search1, animated: true)

    }
}
```

Comment: An entire text of the error would be helpful.

Comment: You have just redeclared a `searchBarButton1` (which is immediately discarded because it's unused afterwards). What you meant instead is probably `var searchBarButton1: UIBarButtonItem!` (instead of an outlet) and `searchBarButton1 = UIBarButtonItem...` instead of redeclaring a `var`. Also, your action signature (`opensearchbar1`) is not correct since it doesn't account for sender...

Comment: Okay I took them out. But I had created a 'test' function that opens a new viewcontroller, but everytime I run it, it crashes with a SIGBART under the delegates.

Comment: Am I missing something to allow the function to work when pressing the button in the app?

Comment: Two ideas: 1) set a breakpoint in your action method to see if it's executed and what line it crashes on, 2) post the crash log so we can see the error and what leads up to it.

Comment: I added a func at the bottom that I thought would make it work, but I still get a SIGBART error referencing "opensearchbar1"  (at the bottom)

Comment: It is giving me the error "unrecognized selector sent to instance "searchBarButton1".

Comment: Got it figured out. I changed the function code to outside the ViewdidLoad, and also added @objc before it.